# Why does my double layered map not work?

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, type-erasure

I have this code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class StorageCenter {
    protected HashMap<Class<?>,HashMap<String,?>> storage;
    public <T> void put(Class<T> c,String key, T value){
        if(!storage.containsKey(c)){
            storage.put(c, new HashMap<String,T>());
        }
        storage.get(c).put(key, value);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public<T> T get(Class<T> c,String key){
        return (T) storage.get(c).get(key);
    }
}
```

I expect that these methods should work, allowing me to have a "double" hash map,  where the first layer is a Class object and the second layer is a HashMap of that type of object.

However this code does not work, I get a compile error when I try to use it:

```
storage.get(c).put(key, value);
```

Why is this not legal code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` does not mean 'Any Type' it means 'Unknown Type.'  Therefore it is not legal to add anything to that map, because you don't know what types are legal to add.  If you want to be able to add anything, the type parameter is `Object`.

Comment: You see I want to make the hash map take a Class of any type have the sub map only hold objects of that type.

Comment: Generics are a compile time feature in java, you can't have generics enforce constraints that aren't known until someone actually adds data at runtime.  This is why you have to "hide" the lack of compile time safety behind an API with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") on it.